# Git/Bower Issue Error: bad line length character

Tags: git, bower, bower-install

I cannot install jquery or any other package from bower.
If I use the direct `git` command (below), it works fine.

```
git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
```

Bower has no issues on my server, but on my client dev machine, bower just doesn't work. 
Is it a firewall issue?

[image]

I've tried the following fix, but to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Are both machines running Windows?

Comment: Yes one is Win 7 the other Win Svr 2012 (Svr works).

Comment: Same version of Git?

Comment: 1.9.4-preview for Windows 7
1.9.4-preview for win Svr 64 bit

Comment: This error means that git received an answer which does not follow its protocol. Most likely this is a firewall or proxy which returned an unexpected response. The weird thing is that you are able to run the same command from the same machine without a problem

Comment: Thanks..yah must be a proxy or firewall issue then.

Answer (score 0):

Discretion Advised:
Environment Windows:

1. Go to your GIT installation bin folder `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<xxx>\bin`
2. copy all file `lib*.dll`
3. Go to your GIT installation bin folder `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<xxx>\libexec\git-core`
4. Paste all files `lib*.dll` copied in step 2

This worked for me.